# CGContextSelectFont equivalent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, core-text

In iOS7 CGContextSelectFont is deprecated. Deprecation message says that I have to use Core Text, but I don't know which is the exact equivalent of this piece of code:

```
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", kBarLabelSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix (context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, barX, barY, [@"Some text" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], [barValue length]);
```

I've been able to create the font with this code:

```
CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrStr = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), kBarLabelSize, NULL);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTFontAttributeName, font);
```

But now haw can I "draw" a text with this font into the context?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As best I can understand from your code, the exact equivalent is:

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill); // This is the default
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill]; // This is the default
[@"Some text" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(barX, barY)
           withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"
                                                                size:kBarLabelSize]
                            }];
```

Note that your calls to `CGContextSetTextDrawingMode` and `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` are setting the  values to the defaults. Your call to `CGContextSetTextMatrix` is not needed when using UIKit drawing like this.

I have no idea what `[barValue length]` is here, however. I'm assuming that you simply incorrectly used this for the length of `@"Some text"`. (`length` is not the number of bytes which is what you need. What you probably meant was `[barValue lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`).

Note that UIKit string drawing (seen here) wraps Core Text.

Comment: I can't test it until now... and it works!. And yes, [barValue length] refers to @"Some text" length and yes, it was incorrectly used, I should use lengthOfBytes, but due to this works I don't realize it was wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: Amazing and useful answer. However: the `setFill` is being ignored. Any hints?

Comment: You can't use `setFill`, in my experience. I'm using this guy: `NSDictionary *fontAsAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textColor};`

Comment: How do you tell `drawAtPoint:withAttributes:` to use the given context? It looks like it uses the default one, which would likely be incorrect.

Comment: @fishinear Why would the default one likely be incorrect? In most cases it's exactly what you want. If you want to change the current context, use the `UIGraphics` functions to set the context (`UIGraphicsPushContext`, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContext...`)

Comment: Ah, cool, `UIGraphicsPushContext` was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I have found, at least in my case, the problem with the new NSString.drawAtPoint interface is that it may draw upside down, depending on how you are using the context.

An alternate is to use the Core Text methods, specifically the CTLine interface thusly:

```
NSDictionary *attribs = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]};

NSAttributedString *fontStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"some text" attributes:attribs];

CTLineRef displayLine = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString( (__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)fontStr );
CGContextSetTextPosition( ctx, xPosition, yPosition );
CTLineDraw( displayLine, ctx );
CFRelease( displayLine );
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use the following to replace it.

1. `CGContextSetFont`
2. `CGContextSetFontSize`

Comment: This is not compatible with `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` (which is also deprecated anyway)