# iOS: Change size of text on GMSMarker when Google map zoomed in/out

Tags: ios, google-maps, text, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I have created a Google map view where I am setting markers on their respective positions and and adding some text over them. Now I want to change size of that text as per zoom, means that size should be bigger on zoom out and lesser on map zoom in. How to achieve the same ? I tried different logic but failed. I am creating that marker text using following function,

// Add text to UIImage

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1 red:(int)red green:(int)green blue:(int)blue alpha:(float)Alpha{

    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;
    //lon = h - lon;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

    char * text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//Here I set size of text
        CGContextSelectFont(context, "HelveticaNeue-Bold", 15, kCGEncodingMacRoman);


    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextInvisible);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 0, text, strlen(text));
    // Then get the position of the text and set the mode back to visible:
    CGPoint pt = CGContextGetTextPosition(context);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1); // black - for shadow
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, (w/2) - (pt.x / 2) + 1, h/2, text, strlen(text));



    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, red, green, blue, Alpha); // white - for text


    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, (w/2) - (pt.x / 2), h/2, text, strlen(text));
    CGImageRef imageMasked=nil;
    imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
} // addText
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972584/4195406 this answer might help you.